# Django+backbone+tastypie: handling relationship

Tags: django, model, backbone.js, foreign-keys, tastypie

Assuming that i have Django models Category and Item, with Item that have ForeignKey towards Category (this field is named category), i have made Item model in Backbone like this:

```
defaults:{ name:'', category_id:''}
```

but when i save model an Item i get the error:

`raise self.field.rel.to.DoesNotExist\n\nDoesNotExist\n`

in django/db/models/fields/related.py, it seems that category_id field is not recognized as field of Item model.

I'm using tastyapi, and ItemModel and the ItemResource are:

```
class Item(models.Model):
  id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
  category=models.ForeignKey('categories.Category')
  name = models.CharField(max_length=300)

class ProductResource(ModelResource):
  category=fields.ForeignKey(CategoryResource,'category')

class Meta: 
    queryset= Product.objects.all()
    resource_name='product'
    authorization= Authorization()
```

Some details: when related.py file executes `val = getattr(instance, self.field.attname)` self.field.attname is store_id but isntance.store_id is None, even if backbone model has, as store_id value, 26.

Some help?

Comment: here is my answer to another user on how to save items with relations http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10242494/tastypie-nested-resource-field-not-found/10583541#10583541

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I have resolved as your linked answer.